# Fastest way of find roots of polynomial defined over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

Suppose we have polynomial $G(x)$ of degree $d$, where $d$ is a large value (e.g. $10^6$). The polynomial is defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for a large prime number $p$ (e.g. $p$ is 200-bit).

We all know that we can factorize the polynomial and then find the roots of each polynomial of degree one. But factorization computation complexity is $O(d^2)$

---

**Question:** Is there any faster way of finding roots of the polynomial?

Comment: How do you factorize in $O(d^2)$ time?

Comment: @skyking I used the following as my reference:  http://www.shoup.net/papers/lille.pdf